# Regex for phone number

Tags: java, regex, jtable

I can search on every column except Number. I cannot search number column. Because I have given the regex as

```
RowFilter<MyTableModel, Object> rf = null;
//If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
try {
    rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0,1,2,3,4);
} catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
    return;
}
sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
```

Can anybody help me to find the  correct Regex. The current Regex is not working for '+'. If i print the exception it will shows

```
meta character '+' near index 0 (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException)
```

I can search the current table columns except number using `RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0,1,2,3,4);` this regex.

```
FirstName   LastName     Number

Karthy      Smith        +123
John        Doe          +234
Sue         Black        +545
Jane        White        +895reading
```

Comment: show us your regex . :)

Comment: Please show us the regex, the input string and the expected output string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(Pattern.quote(filterText.getText()), 0,1,2,3,4);
```

as `filter.getText()` may (and in your case does) contain regex meta characters or escape sequences, they lose their special meaning using [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Can we search as case sensitive if so please guide me

Comment: @Abin: it should be case sensitive by default. Do you mean case insensitive?

Comment: Can we search as case insensitive? if so please guide me

Comment: @Abin: yes you can. Instead of using the `regexFilter()` method, you have to extend `RowFilter` and override `include()`